# Return a value from a method

Tags: android, methods

I have this method to get the user location and I want to return `myLocation` variable :

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if (location != null) {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                LatLng mylocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            }
        }
    });
```

I have this method inside of a function that returns a LatLng value but I can't get the value from inside of the method.

Comment: Type your full method here. and i keep in mind that location is a service and you have to handle your code depends on callback events

Comment: @AbuQauod the full method is already there

Comment: Use Broadcast Receiver or Bus for this.

Comment: @SaurabhVadhvaI can't use it because I need the location then I call the function

Answer (score -1):

Declare the Fused Location Client class

```
private Location currentLocation; 

public Location getCurrentLocation() {
    return currentLocation;
}

mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if (location != null) {
                 this.currentLocation= location;
            }
        }
    });
```

after getCurrentLocation() that process the your current location LatLng

```
        if (getCurrentLocation()  != null) {
            double latitude = getCurrentLocation() .getLatitude();
            double longitude = getCurrentLocation() .getLongitude();

            LatLng mylocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        }
```

Comment: can't you be more specific?